# Combine stats() and ar2() in esttab output

Tags: stata

The Stata documentation for `esttab` says

> stats() disables r2(), ar2(), pr2(), aic(), bic(), scalars(), sfmt(), noobs, and 
>   obslast.

It's a bit unfortunate!

How can I show the R-Squared and also the result of the test in the following model? I'm using `eststo` and `esttab` to store and output the results. It seems I can either call `esttab, stats(test)` and show the model estimates and the result of the test and the bottom, or call `esttab, ar2` and show the R-Squared at the bottom, but can't combine the two.

Is there any workaround for this?

```
sysuse auto
eststo clear
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
quietly test        (_cons=0) (_b[fs]=1)
estadd scalar test=r(p)

esttab, stats(test)

esttab, ar2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

eststo clear
eststo: regress price weight mpg

test (_cons=0) (_b[weight]=1)

estadd scalar test = r(p)
estadd scalar r = e(r2_a)

esttab, stats(test r, fmt(%8.4f))
```

This saves the adjusted R^2 [`e(r2_a)`] returned from regression estimation (a stored result) and uses it within the `stats()` option. Type `help stored results` for details.

Note that the `esttab` command is a wrapper for the `estout` command, so you may want to read on that too. These commands are available within the `ESTOUT` user-written module, by Ben Jann at SSC.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call stored estimation results within the stats() option directly.

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

eststo clear
eststo: regress price weight mpg

test (_cons=0) (_b[weight]=1)

estadd scalar test = r(p)

esttab, stats(test r2_a, fmt(%8.4f))
```